# error 500 on joomla Global Configuration save

Tags: joomla

I'm new to joomla and I'm configuring my first site, but ended having a problem with the Global Configuration, when I try to save it, i receive a 500 error.

I'm using php internal server to run it, "php -S localhost:8081"... everything else is working fine..

here's the stacktrace, doesn't seem to be a permission error, but i'm not sure.

```
500 - An error has occurred.

JModel: :getName() : Can't get or parse class name.

Return to Control Panel
Call stack
# Function Location
1 JAdministrator->dispatch() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/administrator/index.php:46
2 JComponentHelper::renderComponent() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/administrator/includes/application.php:153
3 JComponentHelper::executeComponent() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:351
4 require_once() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:383
5 JController->execute() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/administrator/components/com_config/config.php:18
6 ConfigControllerApplication->save() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:761
7 JController->getModel() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/administrator/components/com_config/controllers/application.php:55
8 JController->createModel() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:793
9 JModel::getInstance() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:599
10 JModel->__construct() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php:201
11 JError::raiseError() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php:220
12 JError::raise() /home/dshiga/dev/joomla_hairs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

Comment: You may have file ownership issues and may need to use the FTP layer if your host does not have suphp or similar installed.

Comment: Thanks Elin, found out my problem, it was by using php -S server. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out, the problem is caused by the use of php internal server through "php -S" command, not sure of exactly what causes the error in this circustances, but hosting the site under apache solved the problem.